# Im trying to upload a file with express and fileupload, but I cant get it to work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, react-hooks

So this is the first time Im trying to upload files to the server, and I started following a tutorial to builöd backend and frontend in react, but I cant get it to work.
My backend is now working with some adjustments, Ive been trying it out in postman and my uploaded files end up in the uploads folder.
But when I try it out in the browser with my frontend I cant get it to work, I only get my console.log string 'msg No file uploaded', but not the actual msg from backend.

Anyone that can see where I written wrong? 
I've compared it with similar code, I've tried to change a bunch of stuff but I can't see why or what is missing?

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const path = require("path")
var moment = require('moment')

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

// enable files upload 
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(fileUpload())

app.use(express.static('./public'));

//middlewares
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world')
})

app.get('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.files.file', req.files.file)
    res.json(req.files.file) //files should give the uploaded file
    res.json(req.body.file) //body should give the name and description field
})

//Upload endpoint 
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.files === null) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' })
        }

        const file = req.files.file
        const fileName = file.name
        //const description = req.body
        //const date = moment().add(10, 'days').calendar()
        const extension = path.extname(fileName)

        const allowedExtensions = /xml|jpeg|jpg|pdf/

        if (!allowedExtensions.test(extension)) throw "Unsupported file type!";

        //.mv() = move the file to current dir/client(react)/public
        file.mv(`${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/${file.name}`)

        res.json({
            message: 'File uploaded successfully!',
            fileName: file.name,
            description: req.body,
            date: moment().add(10, 'days').calendar(),
            filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}`
        })
    } catch (err) {     //catch if path doesn't exist
        console.error(err)
        //500 server error
        return res.status(500).send(err)
    }
})

//make uploads directory static
app.use(express.static('uploads'));

//Delete endpoint
//app.delete('/upload')

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

fileUpload.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const FileUpload = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState('')
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState('Choose File')
    const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0])
        setFileName(e.target.files[0].name) //this should change the name in {fileName}
    }

    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', file)
        console.log('file', file)

        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
                header: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })

            const { fileName, filePath } = res.data
            console.log('res.data', res.data)

            setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath })
            console.log('setUploadedFile', fileName, filePath)

        } catch (err) {
            if (err.response.status === 500) {
                console.log('There was a problem with the server')
            } else {
                console.log('msg No file uploaded', err.response.data.msg)
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className='custom-file'>
                    <input
                        type='file'
                        name='file'
                        className='custom-file-input'
                        id='customFile'
                        onChange={onChange} />
                    <label
                        className='custom-file-label'
                        htmlFor='customFile'>{fileName}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input
                    type='submit'
                    value='Upload file'
                    className='btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4'
                />
            </form>

            {uploadedFile ? (
                <div>
                    <h3>{uploadedFile.fileName}</h3>
                    <img scr={uploadedFile.filePath} alt='' />
                </div>
            ) : null} 
        </>
    )

}

export default FileUpload
```

Comment: What is the output of `err.response.status`?

Comment: @curious_coder I don't get the err.response.status, I only get my console.log string 'msg No file uploaded' if thats what you mean. 
If I check my console in inspector I get 404 when trying to post?
Sorry Im new to this so maybe I missunderstod you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend server is running on the port 5000(Assuming you haven't set the variable of `process.env.PORT`), therefore the url should be `http://localhost:5000` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

The `axios.post('/upload', ...)` is posting data to react url. Hence 404 error.

```
const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', formData, {
                header: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })
```